# Bring old files from a behind branch into new branch, while keeping the new files

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-bash, pull-request

I am a total git noob.

I had a branch called `master` which had the following 2 files.

- foo.js
- bar.js

I created a new branch from `master`

`git checkout -b develop`

I then continued to work on `foo.js` & `bar.js` in a series of commits.

After I decided to rename those new updated files

- foo.js -> (renamed to) foo.help.js
- bar.js -> (renamed to) bar.help.js

Now my `develop` branch which is 10-15 commits ahead of `master` branch. Has these 2 files

- foo.help.js
- bar.help.js

What I want to do is, merge my branch `develop` with `master` in such a way where I can get the following files in `develop` branch

- foo.js // old file from master
- foo.help.js
- bar.js // old file from master
- bar.help.js

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834939/dont-let-git-rename-files-during-merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out specific files from branches:

```
git checkout master
git checkout develop -- foo.help.js bar.help.js
```

Check out the documentation for more information:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203

Comment: I have a total 90+ files, should I do this for every file?

Comment: That's  a slightly different story. If my Git understanding is correct, checkout should have the same semantics for trees (directories) as for blobs (files) as opposed to commits, which means you should be able to list directories after the double dash. If you only want some of the files on some of your directories, you might want to consider doing the merge the other way, i.e., check out the files from master into develop, and then merge back into master (if you're okay with having the files on develop as well).

Comment: Thank you for this,  your answer helped me pave in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So what helped me was this solution, since I had to move more then 100+ files. While keeping the old ones.

1- `git checkout develop` (Go into the branch where you want the copied files to be moved to) For me in this case was `develop` because I wanted to move `foo.js` file to my `develop` branch. Where `foo.help.js` existed

2- `git checkout master [file/path/will/come/here]` what this will do is take all the files in that certain path in `master` branch & copy those files as well from that specific branch.

So in short

```
git checkout develop
git checkout master docs/src/pages/demos/
```

Thanks to @user2882096 for this help on this.

Comment: No problem, always a pleasure dealing with Git ;)